# Method for keeping MySQL database up to date locally

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, git

I am currently using git as my version control for my php written apps. This is fine for source code.

I am also learning phinx for some database version control, initially I was excited about this as I thought it was a full blown database migration tool, that worked similar to git in that I could "pull" or "push" to and from a database repository, but i can see now it is more for use for database schema changes to be migrated from local to production.

I would like a system that allows me to ensure that my local version of the database is up to date, so for example a customer registers an account on the live site. I should in theory be able to have this change reflected fairly quickly on the local version. It would need to be totally framework independent, i.e easy to integrate into opencart/wordpress and my own frameworks.

It would work in a similar way to a version control system, where I could simply push or migrate the latest production database to some repository, and pull this down to the local version.

Are there any tools out there that do this? And if not can someone advise, theoretically how I could go about writing something like this myself?

Comment: Your schema gets versioned because it is part of your software; it is important to synchronize schema changes with the code that interacts with your database. But (most) data is not part of your application. From a software development perspective, there is generally no need to sync data between instances. In fact, there are good reasons not to, e.g. when testing your application it is often useful to have known data in the database, and having production data in development can be a privacy issue. Are you *sure* you want to automatically sync data from production to development?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you raise some good points alright, Perhaps I need to review my own process. One issue however is if there is html amongst the data (wordpress for instance)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601273/make-a-copy-of-live-mysql-database-periodically